# Laravel with Informix database

Tags: laravel-5.3, informix

I am using an Informix database and it seems like Laravel doesn't support it by default.

How can I use an Informix database with Laravel?

Your help is really appreciated!

I am using PHP 5.6.

Comment: You need to use a external package.

Comment: Improve grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third party package. [Laravel Informix Database Package](https://packagist.org/packages/fhenne/laravel-informix)

Just download it using composer, add the dependency, add the db provider and then publish your new config.

### Step by step

Add to your `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
    "poyii/laravel-ifx": "1.0.0"
}
```

Then run `composer update`

Once Composer has installed or updated your packages you need to register Informix DB. Open up `config/app.php` and find the providers key and add:

```
Poyii\Informix\InformixDBServiceProvider::class,
```

Finally you need to publish a configuration file by running the following Artisan command.

> $ php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: I installed poyii / laravel-ifx, but I can not install the infomix driver on ubuntu.
do you have any idea how to install this driver on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Had the same need, but the above process won't work with newer version of laravel as the package is locked on version `<= 5.2`, so you will have to overwrite the repository to fix it.

I have documented the process for my self here: https://blog.rabin.io/sysadmin/laravel-lumen-informix